# Issues with sorting by group in order to find the SD

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I am trying to use the summarize by groups function in order to create Confidence Intervals by groups. When I run the code with just the mean it works, but when I add in the the code to get

Error in `summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `N_autonomous = n(autonomous)`.
ℹ In group 1: `yeargroup = 5`.
Caused by error in `n()`:
! unused argument (autonomous)

I ran this code and was hoping to get the SDs for each group

```
auto_means <- motivation %>%  
  group_by(yeargroup) %>%  
  summarize(mean_autonomous=mean(autonomous),
            sd_autonomous=sd(autonomous),
            N_autonomous= n(autonomous),
            se=sd_autonomous/sqrt(N_autonomous),
            upper_limit=mean_autonomou+se,
            lower_limit=mean_autonomou-se 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because `n()` returns the number of individuals in each group that you are grouping by (i.e., `yeargroup`). So, if you want to find the number of individuals in `yeargroup`, simply specify `n()` with an empty argument if you are already grouping by `yeargroup`. See the help files for more details (i.e., `?n()`).

```
set.seed(1)
data<-data.frame(
  group=rep(1:10,times=1,each=5),
  year=rep(1:5,times=10,each=1),
  x=rnorm(50)
)
library(tidyverse)
auto_means <- data %>%  
  group_by(year) %>%  
  summarize(mean_x=mean(x),
            sd_x=sd(x),
            N_year=n(),
            se=sd_x/sqrt(N_year),
            upper_limit=mean_x+se,
            lower_limit=mean_x-se 
  )
```

Also, you can always use `length()` instead of `n()` to get the number of individuals in a different group (although they should give you the same number).

```
set.seed(1)
auto_means <- data %>%  
  group_by(year) %>%  
  summarize(mean_x=mean(x),
            sd_x=sd(x),
            N_x=length(x) 
  )
```